# error in detecting the device phone number in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have to get the device phone no in which my application is installed.I tried lot of ways.Searched google also.Bhe code that i am getting is for imei number,not the mobile no ??

But not got the result

I tried using

http://pastebin.com/15GMazLv

Can anyone guide me
how to implement this ??

I will be really thankful to you

Regards
Tushar Sahni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
TelephonyManager tmgr=(TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) ; 
String phoneNum = tmgr.getLine1Number();
```

Comment: ,,,I have tried this,,But it giving imie number,,,,,i want the telephone number of the device,,,,